# UI button not showing on the storyboard but on emulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using Xcode 10.3 to build a project.
When I'm set a button image, it can be shown on the storyboard.
[image]

However I tried it on the emulator it seems to be OK.
How can I get them the image shown on the storyboard same as on the emulator? [image]

Comment: Where did you set the button image ?

Comment: in Xcode there is no emulator - only simulator. How did you set the image: with Storyboard or programmatically?

Comment: You have to give height and weight to Record button to show properly on screen. Currently, it's showing on the basis of image size in button.

Answer (score 0):

Change image name in asset file and then set image again in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to rebuild code again and see or remove image and set it again

Answer (score 0):

Give both button and image width and height. Because without width and height the button's size will depend on the images's default size which is bigger than the size you want.